# Multiple Graph Panes Per ZedGraphControl?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to put more than one graph pane in one zedGraphControl?  So each zedGraphControl appears to have only one chart in a single control.  I want to be able to add more than one chart to a particular zedGraphControl if that is possible.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new [GraphPanes](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_ZedGraphControl_GraphPane.htm) via the [MasterPane](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_MasterPane.htm)-Property of the ZedGraphControl class:

```
GraphPane newPane = new GraphPane();
zedGraphControl.MasterPane.Add(newPane);
```

The GraphPane-Property of ZedGraphControl always accesses the first GraphPane in the MasterPane-List.